# Already executed Unit-Tests in MTM 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing

I have build VS 2010 Solution with tests and everything is OK.

Now, while bringing these automated tests in MTM 2010, SHOULD I execute thhem again ?

I could not see that they are already executed and successful.

Many many thanks for your support in advance
Nassim

Comment: MTM is for manual or automated UI tests only. It is usually not used to store and maintain unit tests. Because what sort of test steps would you write into a unit test case? To see the results of the tests from a build you cannot use MTM, that's only possible with the Team Services "Build" tab. Also MTM can only be used when the build is already built, because you need to assign a build from a build definition to a test plan.